# Aggregate contiguous rows

Tags: r

I have a `data.frame` in R with a series of variables

```
userID (numeric) var1 (factor) var2 (factor) time (character) action (character)
```

The first 3 columns are the same for each user session, which can have many rows. However, `time` and `action` change for each row.

I have tried `aggregate` to combine the entire session (contiguous rows) into a single row.

```
dat <- aggregate(cbind(time, action) ~ userID + var1 + var2, 
    data = log, FUN = paste, collapse = "|")
```

That would solve my problem if users only appeared in the file once. However, that is not the case and the above line aggregates all sessions into a single row.

How can I avoid that? How do I aggregate contiguous rows (sessions) only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like what MrFlick said, except create the `user.session` variable with:

```
rle <- with(log, rle(as.character(interaction(user, var1, var2))))
log$user.session <- rep(seq_along(rle$lengths), rle$lengths)
```

It just seems easier to understand for us mere mortals...

Answer (score 0):

I would create a user.session ID such that each continuous sequence of rows for a given user/var1/var2 are assigned a unique ID. First, a sample data set

```
log<-data.frame(
    user = rep(c(1,2,3,1,3,4), times),
    var1 = factor(rep(letters[c(1,2,3,1,3,4)+7], times)),
    var2 = factor(rep(letters[c(1,2,3,1,3,4)+13], times)),
    time = "a",
    action="b",
    stringsAsFactors=F
)
```

Now we add the user.session id

```
log$user.session<-with(log, 
    ave(seq_len(nrow(log)),user,var1,var2,FUN=function(x) {
       cumsum(c(0,diff(x))!=1)
    })
)
```

And now you can do

```
dat <- aggregate(cbind(time, action) ~ user + var1 + var2 + user.session, 
    data = log, FUN = paste, collapse = "|")
```

which gives

```
  user var1 var2 user.session          time        action
1    1    h    n            1     a|a|a|a|a     b|b|b|b|b
2    2    i    o            1         a|a|a         b|b|b
3    3    j    p            1             a             b
4    4    k    q            1         a|a|a         b|b|b
5    1    h    n            2           a|a           b|b
6    3    j    p            2 a|a|a|a|a|a|a b|b|b|b|b|b|b
```

Answer (score 0):

So in bed I had the same realization which is to add a user.session column. I like both of your solutions but the second one is easier to understand and that is why I chose it. In any case, this is a third possibility

log$user.session <- cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(log$userID)!=0))

Then, including this column in the aggregate function does the trick as well.

Cheers.